# I'm trying to overload << operator and print out emp.name

Tags: c++, linked-list, operator-overloading

I am trying to make a linked list. I have 3 classes - `Employee`, `ListOfEmployee`, and `NodeofEmployee`. All of the functions are stored in a header file.

Employee class

```cpp
class Employee {
    friend class NodeofEmployee;
public:
    Employee();
    Employee(string n, double s); 
                
private:
    string name;
    double salary = 0;
};
```

ListOfEmployee class

```cpp
class ListOfEmployee {
private:
    NodeofEmployee* head;               //getting point to NodeofInt class
        
public:
    ListOfEmployee();                   //constructor
    ~ListOfEmployee();                  //destructor
    void insertAtfront(string, double);         //insert value to the back
    void getSalary(string name);                //prints of value
    int deleteMostRecent();         //delete last value
    void display();
    friend ostream& operator <<(ostream& outputStream, const ListOfEmployee& e);
};
```

NodeofEmployee class

```cpp
class NodeofEmployee {
    friend class ListOfEmployee;
public:
    NodeofEmployee(int id, string name);
private:
    Employee emp;               
    NodeofEmployee* next;           //the address of the next value     
};
```

I want to overload `operator<<`, but it won't let me print out the employee name and salary:

```cpp
ostream& operator <<(ostream& outputStream, const ListOfEmployee& e) {
    NodeofEmployee *newpptr = e.head;
    while (!e.head) {
        outputStream << newpptr;
    }
    
    return outputStream;
}
```

Comment: Please show a [mre], where have you declared your operator? What error are you seeing?

Comment: I think you need an `ostream& operator <<(ostream& outputStream, const NodeofEmployee & e) {` also I expect in `outputStream << e.head;` e.head is a pointer.

Comment: And then after that a `operator<<` for `Employee`

Comment: `outputStream << *e.head;` might help, otherwise you'll just get the address of the pointer

Comment: @drescherjm I've pasted in NodeofEmployee, Employee but they didn't seem to work not sure if I did it right or note

Comment: `ostream& operator <<(ostream& outputStream, const ListOfEmployee& e) {` Probably should traverse the whole list. Printing each node instead of just the head node.

Comment: My advice how to solve this is create an operator<< for `Employee`. Then create one for `NodeofEmployee`. Then work on the one for `ListOfEmployee`. You are starting in the wrong place. Also make sure you follow mine and @AlanBirtles advice about how to create `ostream& operator <<(ostream& outputStream, const ListOfEmployee& e) {`

Comment: @drescherjm I've updated the ostream but still does'nt work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So there are (at least) two errors here

```
ostream& operator <<(ostream& outputStream, const ListOfEmployee& e) {
    NodeofEmployee *newpptr = e.head;
    while (!e.head) {
        outputStream << newpptr;
    }
    return outputStream; 
}
```

The first error is the `newpptr` is not an `Employee`, it's a `NodeofEmployee` pointer. To print the `Employee` you need

```
        outputStream << newpptr->emp;
```

The second error is that although you have written a while loop, you aren't actually looping though your list. `newpptr` never changes in your loop, and the loop condition is wrong. I think you want something like this

```
    NodeofEmployee *newpptr = e.head;
    while (newpptr) {
        outputStream << newpptr->emp;
        newpptr = newpptr->next;
    }
```

The third apparent problem is that you haven't defined an `operator<<` for `Employee`. So you need to add this

```
class Employee {
    ...
    friend ostream& operator <<(ostream& outputStream, const Employee& e);
};
```

It's in this final `operator<<` that you will print the name and salary.

```
    ostream& operator <<(ostream& outputStream, const Employee& e)
    {
        outputStream << e.name << ' ' << e.salary << '\n';
        return outputStream;
    }
```

Comment: is there a way I can print out the employee details from the Listofemployee

Comment: Why would you want to? The name and salary are private in `Employee` so firstly you would have to write public getter methods to access the values. Then you would have to modify the code in Listofemployee to use those methods. So it's possible, but I would rather see something like the code I wrote.

Comment: Now that I mentioned it I see the `emp` and `next` in NodeofEmployee are also private. So the code I wrote won't work either. You need to have a think about what data you want to make accessible (and how) in your classes.